# warning.js:19 Warning: [antd: Menu] `children` is deprecated. Please use `items` instead

Tags: reactjs, antd

have a project that contains several interfaces, and among these interfaces there is an interface that contains a sidebar, and I use a “menu” for the sidebar.

But I got this problem:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button , Menu, Typography, Avatar} from 'antd';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {HomeOutlined, MoneyCollectOutlined, BulbOutlined, FundOutlined, MenuOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons'
import icon from '../images/cryptocurrency.png'


const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className='nav-container'>
        <div className='logo-container'>
            <Avatar src={icon} size="large"/>
            <Typography.Title level={2} className='logo'>
                <Link to="/">Cryptoverse</Link>
                {/* <button className='menu-control-container'></button> */}
            </Typography.Title>
        </div>

        <Menu mode="vertical" theme="dark">
              <Menu.Item key="home" icon={<HomeOutlined/>}>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="cryptocurrencies" icon={<FundOutlined/>}>
                <Link to="/cryptocurrencies">Cryptocurrencies</Link>
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="exchanges" icon={<MoneyCollectOutlined/>}>
                <Link to="/exchanges">Exchanges</Link>
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="news" icon={<BulbOutlined/>}>
                <Link to="/news">News</Link>
              </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

I tried using props but getting same error on console.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of `children` deprecation warning you should refactor your `Menu` component to new `items` architecture:

```
const items: MenuProps['items'] = [{
  label: <Link to="/">Home</Link>,
  icon: <HomeOutlined/>,
  key: 'home'
}, {
  ... etc
}]

....

<Menu mode="vertical" theme="dark" items={items} />
```

You can read more about these changes in [docs](https://ant.design/components/menu).